# How to create a custom bash command in linux

Tags: linux, shell, command

The question is about bash shell commands in ubuntu 10.04.
I have created a simple addition program in c and it works fine in my terminal.
Now I want to make this program to execute into my terminal as a command.

How can I convert a C program into a bash shell command?
How to make that command an system command like others?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but I assume what you're looking for is adding the path of your application to the system path.

Comment: if you call your cmd as `./myCmd` or `/path/to/myCmd`, either copy/move `myCmd` to `/usr/local/bin`, or add `export PATH="/path/to:$PATH" to your `.bash_profile`. (assuming `/usr/local/bin/` is in your PATH already). Else you'll have to give us an example "I want `myCmd` to work like `xxxx` (a std command in bash)`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yout just have to change it's owner & group root following commands
**sudo chown root "file_name"**
**sudo chgrp root "file_name"**
then give this command to change the permissions
**sudo chmod 755 "file_name"**
and place it in **/bin** with this command
**sudo mv "file_name" /bin**

now u can run it as a normal command.

Comment: It's working fine as I wanted before.. Thank you so much for to the point answer..

Answer (score 0):

You run your code by ./compiled-c-program
If you like to run like the other "system" program you need to add a static link to your program to one of the folder from your $PATH variable e.g.:
ln -s ~/bin/c-compiled-c-program path/to/the/program/compiled-c-program

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this C program to be executed by any user, as a system command. If this is your requirement, then you can add an execute permission to everyone by `chmod +x <program name>`  and then add the program absolute path in the system define `PATH` environment variable.